# \headheight warning with image in header

Tags: fancyhdr

In the Overleaf, when I compile , I get this warning constantly:

*Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): Make it at least 106.59952pt.*

This is my work:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}\\Το Θεώρημα Μοναδικότητας του \textlatin{Alexandrov}, Δημήτριος Στεργίου}
\title{Διπλωματική Εργασία}
\author{Δημήτρης Στεργίου}
\date{Σεπτέμβριος 2021}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{Εισαγωγικές Έννοιες}
\end{document}
```

How can I fix this problem, please?

Comment: well do what it says. Add `headheight=91.8164pt` to the geometry options.